# Sending a Javascript value to MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to send the value P (ive assigned points to radio button selections and P is the total of those selections) to a php file and then to a MySQL database but i'm having trouble with doing it. I know that it cant be done directly. How can I do this?  Any help would be appreciated.

```js
//Javascript
function getRBtnName(GrpName) {
   var sel = document.getElementsByName(GrpName);
   var fnd = -1;
  var str = '';
   for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) {
     if (sel[i].checked == true) { str = sel[i].value;  fnd = i; }
   }
 //  return fnd;   // return option index of selection
 // comment out next line if option index used in line above 
   return str;
 }
  
 function calculateA() {
     var A = getRBtnName('q1') * 1;
     var B = getRBtnName('q2') * 1;
     var C = getRBtnName('q3') * 1;
     var D = getRBtnName('q4') * 1;
     var E = getRBtnName('q5') * 1;
     var F = getRBtnName('q6') * 1;
     var G = getRBtnName('q7') * 1;
  var H = getRBtnName('q8') * 1;
  var I = getRBtnName('q9') * 1;
  var J = getRBtnName('q10') * 1;
  var K = getRBtnName('q11') * 1;
  var L = getRBtnName('q12') * 1;
  var M = getRBtnName('q13') * 1;
  var N = getRBtnName('q14') * 1;
  var O = getRBtnName('q15') * 1;
     
     var P = A + B + C + D + E + F + G + H + I + J +K + L + M + N + O;
     document.formC.totalSectionA.value = P;
  
  document.getElementById('mytotal').value = P;

  $('#mytotal').val( P );

  $.post('main.php', { total : mytotal }, function(data) {
   alert( data );
  } )
 }


    //php code

    <?php
 $servername = "";
 $username = "";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "";
 
 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 
 echo $_POST['total'];
 
    $sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO `ScoreDB`(`team_Id`) VALUES ($total)";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlStatement );
 echo $sqlStatement;
?>
```

Comment: What is your issue, error ?

Comment: Nothing happens or it says unidentified index 'total' on this line: echo $_POST['total'];

Comment: Well, it seems that `mytotal` is undefined because you didn't defined it

Comment: How do I define it? Doesnt this count (document.getElementById('mytotal').value = P;) ?

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `mytotal` is undefined because you didn't defined it. Use the `P` variable like

```
$.post('main.php', { total : P }, function(data) {
    alert( data );
})
```

Or define `myTotal` by `var myTotal = P;` before your request.

Comment: like this?                                                                                            
 var P = A + B + C + D + E + F + G + H + I + J +K + L + M + N + O;
     document.formC.totalSectionA.value = P;
  
  document.getElementById('mytotal').value = P;
  
  $.post('main.php', { total : P }, function(data) {
   alert( data );
  })

  $('#mytotal').val( P );

  $.post('main.php', { total : mytotal }, function(data) {
   alert( data );
  } )
 }

Answer (score -1):

You have to add `session_start()` to the two pages, the one that holds the variable `p` and the `.php` file to pass the variable to.

Then you can pass the variable to the `.php` file like so

```
//On page 1
$_SESSION['varname'] = $var_value;

//On page 2
$var_value = $_SESSION['varname'];
```

After the `.php` page has the variable (you can confirm this by echoing the variable within the .php page and check whether it gives the correct value) you can then pass it to the database

Comment: Thank you. how would you echo the variable?

Comment: @MoD echo "$variablename";